# Shiny observe event executing function as reactive

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to execute a function inside `observeEvent()`

I have

- two predefined functions: `calculate_value()` and `create_my_plot()`
- one input stored as reactive variable: `myreactive()`
- one dataset `a` read from file. File is chosen according to input value.
- `a` is processed with `calculate_value()` and passed to `create_my_plot()`

it goes like this:

```
myreactive<-reactive({input$myinput})
observeEvent(input$clicks,
{
 filename<-paste(myreactive(),".csv")
 a<-read.csv(filename)
 x<-calculate_value(a,b=myreactive())
 output$myplot<-renderPlot(
                   create_my_plot(x,myreactive())
 })
```

Whenever I click action button this event is activated and new plot plotted. But also whenever `myreactive()` is changed this plot is replotted. This is good. But there is a problem with the replotted plot: it still uses "old" version of "x"

I need the function calculate_value() to be reacalculated whenever myreactive() is changed. It doesn't happen

I tried already usinig

```
x<-reactive({ calculate_value(a,b=myreactive()) })
```

but then nothing happens. Namely the function is not executed at all and x is left as null. 
For me this is unacceptable because "myreactive()" is changing the dataset and the description of the plot and if the plot is not re-plotted accordingly it is simply wrong.

It would be enough to delete the plot entirely if myreactive() changes but I actually would like to know what is going on and why I can't have `calculate_value()` re-do calculations each time while `create_my_plot()` can do it.

Comment: could you upload your code for the app to a [gist](https://gist.github.com) (or attach it at the end of your question)? It would be possible to inspect all your code and possibly try the app, running `runGist(key)`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, when I use `observerEvent()`, all things that introduce in this method change when some value changes. Shiny is an framework which utilizes reactive programming. In whatever case, you would use `reactive()`, to reutilize code and to have a clean code. If you use this variable and the value change, the value will change in all locations.

A solution to your problem, it could be to use `observe()` inside `observerEvent()`. Indeed, each time that the values of the intern code changes, the `observe()` will execute everything inside in it.

You can see this example, and try with it:

```
  testReactive<-reactive({as.numeric(input$numberTest)})

  observeEvent(input$bTest,{
    observe({   
                 x<-10+testReactive()
                 output$testing<-renderText(print(x))

            }) #Closed observe
  }) #Closed observeEvent
```